# Linux: Delete every file older than a date with one exceptional file

Tags: linux, file, command-line

I am able to delete lets say all regular files in a folder older than 7 days via:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

with a single problem. There is a file here (.gitignore) which I want to keep. I tried using regex but apparently findutils regex does not have support for negative lookahead `(?!gitignore)`

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `! -name .gitignore`

```
find /path/to/dir ! -name .gitignore -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

You can group multiple arguments within escaped parentheses. Example, to remove all files except `.gitignore` and javascript files (ending in `.js)`:

```
find /path/to/dir ! \( -name ".gitignore" -o -name "*.js" \) -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

`-o` means `or`

Comment: I believe the "!" needs to be escaped, otherwise the shell could try to fit in the previous command? ie `\!` instead of `!` ? (not sure though :/ )

Comment: *man find* mentions the need to escape `!`, although I have never needed to do it. Do you have trouble running the above commands as they are? The shell command for *previous command* is `!!`

Comment: perfect. FYI it does work perfectly for me without escaping !